# Typescript key mapping with an enum

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I am trying to take an enum like this:

```
enum Thing {
  ValA = 'ValA',
  ValB = 'ValB',
  ValC = 'ValC'
}
```

and turn it into a type like this:

```
type CanDos = {
  CanValA: boolean;
  CanValB: boolean;
}
```

Basically just add "Can" to the front of all the enum keys so I can use it like this where the set of "Thing"s is arbitrary:

```
const result = checkIt([ Thing.ValA, Thing.ValB ]);
result.CanValA; // true | false
result.CanValB; // true | false
result.CanValC; // undefined
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I've updated the question with some additional clarification -- I'm hoping to find a way to get the `CanValC` bit to not be present in the final type since it is missing from the `checkIt()` array.

Comment: Why is `CanValC` not in `CanDos`?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77234485/typescript-key-mapping-with-an-enum/77234532#comment136159400_77234485) @cobbdb That's a non-trival change to the meaning of the question, and a considerate solution will depend on whether you want to (1) **include only** `ValA` and `ValB`, or (2) **exclude only** `ValC`. Clarification is needed at minimum, but that should probably become a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to prefix the keys of a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), using the [type utility `Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgFgSxAcygbwFBSgNQIYA2AglALxQBE+xFANFroQEJmXVN0YC+GGALgE8ADsCgBhPCAAiAewDOrAErAAxjIBOAEwA8AAwkgAJGgDWwATIBmUQSKuxEKLrtpQARjJkFgkgHwBuBigAemCAPQB+DCA)

```ts
enum Thing {
  ValA = "ValA",
  ValB = "ValB",
}

type CanDos = Record<`Can${keyof typeof Thing}`, boolean>;
   //^? type CanDos = { CanValA: boolean; CanValB: boolean; }
```

---

> Keep in mind that `Thing` as a *type* refers to a union of the values of the enum, and that `Thing` as a *value* refers to the enum object itself, so it's necessary to refer to the type of the enum using `typeof Thing` in order to derive a union of its keys using the [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the keys of your `Thing` enum to be the new keys of `CanDos` with your nominated prefix

```ts
enum Thing {
  ValA = 'ValA',
  ValB = 'ValB'
}

type CanDos = {
  [K in keyof typeof Thing as K extends string ? `Can${K}` : never]: boolean 
}
```

[image: screenshot of computed type]